# It is possible to combine ValidationSummary(true) and ModelState.AddError("field", "error")?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

- I use ValidationSummary(true) to print model validation errors in
  one place and property validation errors near each field.
- In the controller i add a property error : ModelState.AddError("property","error")

  I see the message validation error for that property but i also got the validation-summary-errors div although i have no model error. 
  What am i doing wrong and why is that div generated if i have no model errors?

  ```
  <div class="validation-summary-errors">
      <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add it twice like so:

```
string errorMessage = "The error message";
//will show in the summary
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errorMessage);
//will show for the prop
ModelState.AddModelError("Prop", errorMessage);
```

Or you can change your call like so:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Changing the argument to `false` will include all Property errors. The param name in `ValidationSummary` is `excludePropertyErrors`, so by passing `true` you are excluding them.

Comment: i want to see in the summary only model related error messages and not properties validation errors. If i add one property error ( having 0 model errors) i still have that div rendered, that is the problem.